# Problem in using WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have created a page which has link to a page of a website. So for showing that on I have used a `WebView` and it works fine.

My Problem is that when I click on any link given on that webpage, the link opens in phone's default browser view. But I want all the links to be opened in my created `WebView`.

Have I made any mistake or it is right..

Please Help Me 
My code is as follows...

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("------------", ".........................................................................................");
        setContentView(R.layout.terms_of_use_web_view_page);

        btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.terms_of_use_button_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(this); 
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.terms_of_use_webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.oomphlink.com/terms-of-use/");


    }
```

Comment: this should be an answer, but I'll comment it anyway.. Research on WebViewClient and shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Comment: Ya you should go with WebViewClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying your own WebViewClient:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById( R.id.terms_of_use_webview );
webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url )
    {
        view.loadUrl( url );
        return true;
    }
});
```

To further understand why this is necessary have a look at the documentation for the  [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
}
```

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for more info...